# Equality in definition of dual space norm

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

In the definition of the dual space norm, the WP page makes the following statement:
[image]

and I was wondering why going from the middle equality to the right equality was obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, because $f$ is linear.

Let's set
$$A = \sup\{|f(x)| : x \in X, \|x\| \le 1\}$$
and
$$B = \sup\left\{\frac{|f(x)|}{\|x\|}, x \in X, x \ne 0\right\}.$$
Suppose $x \in X$ with $\|x\| \le 1$.  If $x=0$ then $f(x) = 0$, so $|f(x)| \le B$.  If $x \ne 0$ then $|f(x)|\le \frac{|f(x)|}{\|x\|}$ since the denominator is at most 1.  So $|f(x)| \le B$ in either case.  Therefore $B$ is an upper bound of the set $\{|f(x)| : x \in X, \|x\|\le 1\}$, so $A \le B$.

Now suppose $x \in X$ with $x \ne 0$.  Set $y = \frac{1}{\|x\|} x$.  Then by linearity $f(y) = \frac{f(x)}{\|x\|}$, so $|f(y)| = \frac{|f(x)|}{\|x\|}$.  Since $\|y\| = 1$, we have $\frac{|f(x)|}{\|x\|} = |f(y)| \le A$.  Thus we have $B \le A$.